# Is there a way to link JDK annotations to requirements?

Tags: java, annotations, trac

Hi guys: Is there an open source way to associate **java @annotations** to **functional requirements**, or for example, TRAC tickets, etc? I want to do something like this:

I'm thinking along the lines of an eclipse plugin which somehow links up with another FOSS project tracking tool, wiki, or maybe even a CSV file.

A somewhat silly but exemplary illustration of what I desire is below:

```
@Requirement WalkDogTwiceADay
public void walkTheDog()
{

}

@Requirement WalkDogTwiceADay
public void dogWalkerThread()
{
   walkTheDog(); //in the morning.
   Thread.sleep(36000000);
   walkTheDog(); //at night
}
```

Comment: Cats don't need to be walked and therefore are better than dogs. Oh wait, this isn't the place for that...

Comment: May annotations are not the right thing for that, but there are [Doclets.][1] This are the "annotations" used in the java doc comments. [1]: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/overview.html

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'm not sure it's a good idea, but it is certainly an interesting one. Just to be sure: are you aware of the fairly common practice of associating version control commits with requirements?

Comment: @PlatinumAzure Yea but dogs don't try to silently kill you in your sleep, so it's kind of a balance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations are metadata, they simply add information to your code for other tools to use or to be inspected at runtime via reflection.

One thing you can do is write an annotation processor that will generate the necessary artefacts. Those could be configuration files, scripts, code...

Another thing you can do is write some tool that knows how to interpret your annotations and uses reflection to find them and take the appropriate actions. For this you'd need to make sure that the annotation type is set to have runtime retention, as opposed to only source or class.

Perhaps some of the stuff found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549144/commonly-reusable-annotations-or-commons-annotations) might prove of use. If that's the case, go ahead and use it. But writing custom annotation processors or code for handling them is not all that terribly hard. The difficult part is getting to know the Java model API that's used by annotation processors, which is like reflection but at compile time (before you have fully-formed classes).

Answer (score 1):

in a previous life, we did something similar with `@requirement #####` annotations, and then had a custom javadoc task that turned the requirement annotations into hyperlinks in the javadocs.

I was going to write an addin for eclipse that turned them into links in the code as well, but never got that far.